# How to show download link for a subscribed product?

Tags: php, mysqli

Using a `function` I can create some parameters to show and hide certain things.

```
function loggedin(){
    return (isset($_SESSION['UserId'])) ? true : false;
}

if (loggedin() === true){
  echo"Welcome $name";
} else {
  echo"<a href="access.php">Log in</a>";
}
```

Another way to hide content for a user is as follows:

```
if (loggedin() === false)
```

How can I make a similar parameter to hide and display data of a product subscribed by a user?

> That is to say when you log in a user who has acquired or who proceeded to subscribe to a product and if the state of the product is `complete` hide the price (or hide some content) and instead of the price show the download link of the file of the product.

How should the consultation be considered and show results?

I have the following table called subscribed this is shaped this way

```
id_subscribed | id_product | UserId | number_facture | status  | date |
     1             5          2         4562344       complete   null
     2             5          9         4562345      incomplete  null
```

The table of products

```
id_product  |  product | price | archive |
    5          null      40.00   data.zip
```

The Users table

```
UserId  | name  | last_name  | usuername | email | password
  2       Juan       null        juan10   @...    q1dxe333f
  9       Pedro      null        pedro1   @...    wfrf653gg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function (or a method in users or product class) that check the relationship between product and user in "subscribed" table.

Using PDO:

```
     /**
     * Check if the relationship between product and user 
     * has status completed.
     *
     * @param  int  $id_product
     * @param  int  $UserId
     * @return boolean
     */
    function checkSubscribeComplete($id_product, $UserId = 1)
    {
        global $pdo; // using PDO
        $res = FALSE; // the default result

        /* Just concat the SQL string.
         * can do directly in $pdo->prepare
         */
        $qString = "SELECT status FROM subscribed";
        $qString .= "  WHERE ";
        $qString .= "id_product = :product";
        $qString .= "  AND ";
        $qString .= "UserId = :user";
        $qString .= "  AND ";
        $qString .= "status = 'complete';";

        $query = $pdo->prepare($qString);

        /* bindValue from PDO, 
         * can use directly if injection was not a problem
         */
        $query->bindValue(':product', $id_product, PDO::PARAM_INT);      
        $query->bindValue(':user', $UserId, PDO::PARAM_INT);

        // Here exec the query
        $query->execute();

        // $result is an array of columns
        $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        // if complete is true we expect to have one column.
        if ( count($result) > 0 ) $res = TRUE;

        return $res;
    }
```

Using MySQLi:

```
/*Not sure if it's works*/
    /**
     * Check if the relationship between product and user 
     * has status completed.
     * Using MySQLi instead of PDO
     *
     * @param  int  $id_product
     * @param  int  $UserId
     * @return boolean
     */
    function checkSubscribeCompleteMI($id_product, $UserId = 1)
    {
        global $con; // using MySQLI, $con is the connection created before
        $res = FALSE; // the default result

        /* Just concat the SQL string.
         */
        $qString = "SELECT status FROM subscribed";
        $qString .= "  WHERE ";
        $qString .= "id_product = '".$id_product."'";
        $qString .= "  AND ";
        $qString .= "UserId = '".$UserId."'";
        $qString .= "  AND ";
        $qString .= "status = 'complete';";

        // exec the query and get the result
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $qString);

        // count the number of rows in the result
        $total = mysqli_num_rows($result); // return int

        // if "complete" is true we expect to have one row.
        if ( $total > 0 ) $res = TRUE;

        return $res;
    }
```

Hope this helps you.

I don't know if you already use PDO, anyway, check [PHP Database Access: Are You Doing It Correctly?](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly--net-25338) if you want to know more about it

Comment: The example is perfect thanks, you can do the same example in mysqli object oriented.

Comment: You can publish in the same answer a second version in mysqli object oriented, is that my projects is in mysqli oreintada to objects. :)

Comment: Sure, now there is a MySQLi example. :)